# Cannot find lib in path

Tags: path, libraries

I am trying to start a program that relies on some libraries that are in my path, however, the program says it cannot find the files:

```
11:45:27 ~ > echo $PATH
/usr/share/fsl/5.0/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/mri/Scripts:/home/mri/Scripts/MRI:/home/mri/Software/BRAINS3/bin:/home/mri/Software/BRAINS3/lib:/home/mri/Software/ITK_Build/bin:/home/mri/Software/ITK_Build/lib:/home/mri/Software/VTK_Build/bin:/home/mri/Software/VTK_Build/lib:/usr/lib/fsl/5.0

11:45:33 ~ > brains3
/home/mri/Software/BRAINS3/bin/brains3_real: error while loading shared libraries: libiplUtils.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

11:45:35 ~ > sudo find / -name libiplUtils.so
[sudo] password for mri: 
/home/mri/Software/BRAINS3/lib/libiplUtils.so
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Libraries aren't looked for in `$PATH` - what's your OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the library search path with the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/mri/Software/BRAINS3/lib
$ brains3
```

You shouldn't set this variable for your whole system. If you can't/don't want to install the software system wide you could create a wrapper script.

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic linker searches for libraries en LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Unix systems tend to sort different types of files into different directories. There are separate directories for executables (e.g. `/usr/bin`), documentation (e.g. `/usr/man`, `/usr/info`, …), native libraries (e.g. `/usr/lib`), Perl libraries (e.g. `/usr/lib/perl5`), and so on. Correspondingly, there are different path variables, all with the same syntax (colon-separated list of directories): `PATH` for executables, `MANPATH` for man pages, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for native libraries¹, `PERL5LIB` for Perl libraries, and so on.

For native libraries, there are system default libraries that are in the search path whether mentioned in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable or not. On Linux, these directories are listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (also, `/lib` and `/usr/lib` are always in the search path).

You therefore have several possibilities:

- Add `/home/mri/Software/BRAINS3/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (Linux-specific, other unix variants may have a similar file). Run `ldconfig` to make the change take effect.
- Add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/mri/Software/BRAINS3/lib` in `/etc/profile` (applies to all users) or in `~/.profile` (applies only to you).
- Make a wrapper script:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/mri/Software/BRAINS3/lib
  exec /home/mri/Software/BRAINS3/bin/brains3 "$@"
  ```
- Create symbolic links to the libraries in `/home/mri/Software/BRAINS3/lib` in another directory on the search path:

  ```
  ln -s /home/mri/Software/BRAINS3/bin/brains3/lib*.so.* /usr/local/lib/
  ```

¹  <sub>`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is the name on most unix variants, but Mac OS X uses `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead.</sub>